# How do I make an image take a DIV's full dimension?

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

I've created a custom "product card" for my site, and I want the images to take the parent's full width and height, regardless of the image's dimensions. I have tried `max-width` `min-width` `max-height` `min-height` and none seem to work. I can't think of any other solution. I'm attaching an image of what I'd like and what I'm achieving now.

https://codepen.io/paulamourad/pen/MdxedG

[image: This is what I need]
[image: Don't want these white spaces]
[image: Don't want these white spaces]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are making a simple layout more complex.
You **don't need to use position properties** in this case. This will make simple layout more complex.

There are different scenarios how to use image more efficiently in webpages, like considering their height-width, and aspect ratio as well.

I have created a Snippet, hope so you will find it useful.
[Bootstrap Cards Snippet](https://codepen.io/Akshay25/pen/byZWGm)

For **dynamic product card images** use the following CSS properties:

```
.card-img-top {
    height: 100px; /* Change it based upon requirement */
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Bootstrap Cards Varation: </h2>
  <h3>Same Aspect Ratio ―</h3>
  <div class="row mb-5">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- row -->
  <h3>Same height for image (Suitable for dynamic different size images) ―</h3>
  <style>
   .cstm-height-card .card-img-top {
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: cover;
   }
  </style>
  <div class="row mb-5 cstm-height-card">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1200x900" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1500x800" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
     <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1400x700" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- row -->
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card mb-3">
     <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x800" class="card-img" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
       <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card mb-3">
     <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x800" class="card-img" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
       <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- row -->
 </div>
```

Comment: This worked!! Any ideas on how to make the image always be centered both horizontal and vertically?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain aspect ratio and don't mind cropping:

```
.product-img-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 260px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden; //This will crop off image portions that overflow the container
}

.card-img-top {
    width: 100%; /*If you specify only width, height will be calculated automatically 
    and aspect ratio is maintained. Similarly, if only height is specified, width is 
    calculated automatically */ 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

You can use the top and bottom in the .card-img-top to position the image.

Answer (score 0):

Use a div with a background image. Set its height to 100%, background-position to center, and background size to cover.

```
.card-img-top {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Works in bootstrap cards, I forked your pen. https://codepen.io/Jason_B/pen/RmdoaQ