# How to set image height and weight that is coming via admin upload

Tags: css, image

My question is when administrators or users upload an image that is large or small in size. How to set the height of an image or div to be a certain size and of the same width in front view

Comment: What have you tried? Show your work please. Setting image size no matter if it is in the div or the image itself all depends on what your end result is. Best to show what you have so someone can help you correctly.

Comment: Might be repeat of this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435831/how-do-i-make-an-image-take-a-divs-full-dimension/56437187]. Just go through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, Hope can help you.

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.image-box{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.image-box img{
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  min-width:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="image-box">
  <img src="image1.png" alt="image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope can help you

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<img src="image.png" />
</div>

<div class="container">
<img src="image2.png" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
}

/* resize images */
.container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```